# setInterval not working on mobile, how to fix?

Tags: html, jquery, mobile, setinterval

```
 jQuery(function ($) { 
     i=0;
     setInterval(function (){
    if(i%2 == 0)
        $('#text1').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#text2').fadeIn('slow')
        })
    else
        $('#text2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#text1').fadeIn('slow')
        })
    i++;
     }, 4000);
 });
```

```
<div id="text1">
  hello
</div>

<div id="text2" style="display:none;">
  hi
</div>
```

Codes above are working on desktop, but not working on mobile. Can't find the error/s. Please point me to the right direction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which mobile did you test on? `setInterval` is standard Javascript and should work on any device.

Comment: Samsung, but also on inspect. Still not working, can't find the issue.

Comment: The problem probably comes from another part of your code. Are there responsive rules based on the device? Maybe your script isn't loaded properly, or JQuery is not included.